# Liquibase is not capable with partial keys?

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I execute sql generated by liquibase and I get:

```
CREATE INDEX `messageId_IDX` ON `messagedetails`(`messageId`);
```

> ERROR 1170 (42000) at line 275: BLOB/TEXT column 'messageId' used in
>   key specification without a key length

My original sql was:

```
CREATE INDEX messageId_IDX ON MessageDetails(MessageID(128))
```

is it a bug in liquibase? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you want to index a TEXT column? (Also using `TEXT` for an ID column doesn't sound right in the first place).

Comment: MessageId is text string that identifies email message. It can be up to 200 chars length. I have index on it, because sometimes I want to search for message by messageId.

Comment: Then use `varchar` not `text`. `text` is for large text columns that contain e.g. HTML or XML code.

Comment: can you say how to use it in hibernate? text is selected by default.

Comment: Sorry I don't do Hibernate. But if `text` is the default, this sounds like a bug in Hibernate (and doesn't improve my opinion of Hibernate)

Comment: Are you sure that creating index on varchar doesn't have limitation on index' field size?

Comment: Well, you would declare the column as `varchar(200)`, so that is not a problem (unless there is another of those stupid MySQL restrictions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Liquibase doesn't support setting an index length. See [this unresolved feature request](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1180) for it, as well as [this mailing list thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/liquibase-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00182.html)